# using for loop and if in php

Tags: php, if-statement, for-loop

I have loop using `for` which results in some values:

`$value1`, `$value2`, `$value3`, `$value4`, ...

How can I make a calculation or relation between these values?

For example, if any two values < 40 echo something?

I hope that some code will make the idea clear:

```
<?php
    $value=$_POST['name']; 
    for($i=1;$i<=$value;$i++)
    {
        $value{$i}=$_POST['name{$i}'];
    }

    if($value{$i} < 40)
    {
        echo "you failed";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "you succeeded";
    } 
?>
```

I want to show the message "you failed" if two values are < 40.

How can I do that?

Comment: why not use a foreeach?

Comment: @Joshua can you explain it more please ?

Comment: check my answer added some comment to it

Comment: Are you trying to test if any two values sum to less than 40?

Answer (score 2):

I'm struggling to make sense of what your current code is actually doing, but that could just be that my PHP is a bit rusty.  Either way, it sounds like the general pattern of what you're *trying* to do is to keep a count of fails and successes.  As an overall structure (that is, *not* to be copied/pasted as-is since I don't know what your `$value` actually is here), it might look something like this:

```
$fails = 0;
$successes = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < len($values); $i++)
{
    if ($values[$i] < 40)
    {
        $fails++;
    }
    else
    {
        $successes++;
    }
}
```

At this point `$fails` contains the count of values less than 40 and `$successes` contains the count of values greater than 40.  Then you invoke your business logic for determining the overall result:

```
if ($fails >= 2)
{
    echo "you failed";
}
else
{
    echo "you succeeded";
}
```

Comment: @bozdoz: Good catch, thanks.  My free-hand PHP is definitely not what it used to be.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as any two values add to less than 40, the "failed" message shows and the loops are exited. If not, the success message shows.

```
$x = false;
foreach ($value as $k1 => $v1) {
      foreach ($value as $k2 => $v2) {
           if (($v1 + $v2) < 40 && ($k1 != $k2)) {
               echo "you failed";
               $x = true;
               break (2);
           }
       }
}
if (!$x) echo "you succeeded";
```

Comment: why the need for the 2 foreach?

Comment: I think the OP is trying to test if any two values in the array sum to 40 "for example if any two values < 40 echo something ?". If that's not what they're asking I'll delete my answer

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question you can use the `foreach` statement

```
$value=$_POST['name']; 
$hasValue = 0;
foreach($value as $key => $dat){ // since we have the value from $_POST we use foreach statement to loop it

    if($dat < 40){ // check if the data in the list is less than 40
         $hasValue++; // increment it if is.
    }
    
  }


 echo ($hasValue > 2)?@"You failed":@"Success"; // check if it has more than 2 less than 40 values.
```

something like the above

and try to read about [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

btw haven't code much in php lately so apologies for some syntax